# ¿Cómo puedo poner un fondo con opacidad a mi video adaptable?

Tags: html, css

Como puedo adaptar el fondo oscuro al tamaño del video, mi video tiene un ancho y alto del 100% al igual que la clase bg pero no se aplica de la misma manera. No quiero aplicar position absolute al video porque sino me rompe el flujo con el section. Estuve investigando con ::before pero parece que esta pseudo clase solo es para imagenes y no para videos T.T alguien que me ayude please

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
   /*--VIDEO DE FONDO--*/
   .bg-video {
   position: relative;
   right: 0;
   top: 0;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   background-size: 100%;
   background: orange;
   background-position: center;
   background-size: contain;
   object-fit: cover;
  }
    
    /*--FONDO OPACIDAD--*/
    .bg {
   position: absolute;
   right: 0;
   top: 0;
   background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
  }
    section {
    width: 100%;
    background: blue;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 20px;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
      <!-- VIDEO -->
     <video class="bg-video">
      <source src="video" type="video/mp4">
     </video>

      <!--FONDO OPACIDAD-->
     <div class="bg"></div>

      <section>
        <h1>TITULO DEL SITIO WEB</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas sagittis, ipsum vitae   facilisis vehicula, nulla felis sagittis sapien, non varius urna ligula vitae ipsum. Sed eget mauris est. Pellentesque est orci, dictum id orci vel, tempor pulvinar augue. Quisque at ullamcorper orci, aliquam tristique est. Etiam eget eros mi. Maecenas non iaculis mauris, a elementum ligula. Ut magna ipsum, pulvinar sit amet arcu quis, venenatis laoreet mauris. Curabitur id feugiat quam. Vestibulum sed odio venenatis, malesuada tortor non, fermentum odio. Phasellus ac auctor ante. Nunc eget tellus erat. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Aliquam tincidunt finibus varius. Nunc ornare tellus non ex molestie aliquam.</p>
      </section>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

EN mi caso, utilice Bootstrap y tambien tuve que crear una hoja de estilo para hacer que el `hero` tenga de fondo un video de fondo y texto arriba. Tambien le agregue una capa para que el texto se pueda ver mejor mientras el video corre de fondo.

HTML

```
<div id="hero">
<video loop muted autoplay poster="">
<source src="video/video-wp2.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
<div class="content d-flex align-items-center" style="text-transform: uppercase;">
<div class="container text-center text-white">
  <h1>Texto</h1>
  <h4>Subtitulo</h4>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#hero {
 position: relative;
 height: 100vh;
}

#hero video {
 background-position: absolute;
 z-index: 10;
 height: 100vh;
 width: 100%;
 object-fit: cover;
}

#hero .content {
 background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5); //capa
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 z-index: 20;
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
}
```

Espero te ayude!

Comment: Gracias pero opte por el plan B que no queria aplicar, modificar el vídeo en premiere

Answer (score 1):

Propongo en esta respuesta resolverlo de este modo:

- Tanto a la etiqueta **`video`** como a la etiqueta **`div`** le aplicamos un ancho de **`50%vh`** para que ocupen la mitad del *vieewport* disponible
- Mantenemos la propiedad **`object-fit`** para que el video que será el contenido se adpate como **`cover`** de su etiqueta
- A la etiqueta que he designado como cortinilla le doy:

  - **`position: absolute;`**: Para sacarla del flujo de nodos
  - **`top: 0;`**: Para indicar que tendrá un desplazamiento de 0 del borde superior hacia el inferior
  - **`width: 100%;`**: Para que cubra al elemento **`video`**

**Código**

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
      <title>Ejemplo</title>
      <style>
        body{
          margin: 0;
        }
        .video-hero {
          background: tomato;
          width: 100%;
          height: 50vh;
          object-fit: cover;
        }
        .video-hero__cortinilla {
          background: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
          height: 50vh;
          position: absolute;
          width: 100%;
          top: 0;
        }
      </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <video controls class="video-hero" src="">
      
    </video>
    <div class="video-hero__cortinilla">
      
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Nota: Lo probé con un video, pero como no creo que sea válido ponerlo entonces solo deje el atributo `controls` y `src` donde tu puedes colocar la referencia a uno y verificar si es que esto te sirve.

Comment: Gracias T.T tengo otra duda respecto a otra cosa que no puedo resolver en css cuando puedas te explico